# Is (3x-5) / 3 an algebraic fraction?

Tags: polynomials

I know that it can be written as $x-\dfrac{5}{3}$ and that's just a polynomial.

But $3$ can be treated as a degree $0$ polynomial and $3x-5$ as a degree $1$ polynomial so shouldn't it in this form be an algebraic fraction?

My mathbook says that it really is an algebraic fraction. So does that mean that any polynomial can be rewritten as an algebraic fraction, but not every algebraic fraction can be simplified to the form of a polynomial? (When $W(x)$[numerator] is not divisible by $P(x)$ [denominator])

Comment: The answer to the latter (main) question is yes.

Comment: All integers are fractions as they are just k/1 = k.  It's the same thing, really.

Comment: Also, technically speaking $3$ is a 0-degree polynomial.  (Although there is very little point in thinking of it in those terms.) so if $P(x) = x - 5 = \sum_{i=0}^1 a_i x^i; a_1 = 1; a_0 = -5$ and $Q(x) = 3 = \sum_{i=0}^0 b_i x^i; b_0 = 3$ then $\frac {P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac {x -5}{3}$.  Kind of silly, but... there it is.

Comment: A fraction of polynomials is a polynomial iff all zeroes in the bot get annihilated by a zero on top. The thing is a polynomial of degree 0 can't have any zero so if it's in the bot of a fraction that fraction is by default a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you realize that $3$ or any $k \in \mathbb R$ is a $0$-degree polynomial than your statements become very clearly correct.

It's almost (not entirely, but almost) the same as noticing that $3 = \frac 31$ is, technically, a fraction as well as being an integer.

So all integers are fractions, but not all fractions are integers.  And all polynomials are algebraic fractions, but not all algebraic fractions are integers.

BTW, you mistyped "fraction" as "function" at one point.